# How to get the current step definition name in Cypress-Cucumber? NOT the scenario name

Tags: cucumber, cypress, mocha.js, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm doing some custom reporting to an API and I'm retrieving bits and pieces of information to put into the payload.

One piece of information I'd like to get is the step definition name ( **not** the scenario name ) at invocation.

I'm sending this information over whenever there is a failure. See the snippet below. Any ideas?

```
  Cypress.on('fail', (error, runnable)=>{
    const errorName = Cypress._.toLower(error.name)
    const message = Cypress._.toLower(error.message)
    const isSkipped = message.includes('skip')
    const stepName = ""
    const wholeMessage = `${stepName} / ${message}`
    if(errorName.includes('error') && isSkipped!=true){
      cy.now('task', 'getValue', 'currentScenario', {log:false}).then(name=>{
        cy.now('postTestResult', "Complete", "Failed", name, wholeMessage)
      })
    }

    if(errorName.includes('error') && isSkipped==true){
      cy.now('task', 'getValue', 'currentScenario', {log:false}).then(name=>{
        cy.now('postTestResult', "Complete", "Skipped", name, wholeMessage)
      })
    }
    throw error
  })
```

Explored the Mocha runnable object & associated methods, including those references from Cypress. Explored online and could not find a reference for retrieving the step definition name from a Cypress Cucumber step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.testState.pickleStep.text` to get the title text for the current running step. The `window.testState` object contains the data for the entire test run. `window.testState.pickles` contains info about all the feature files, `window.testState.pickle` contains the info for the current feature, and `window.testState.pickleStep` contains info on the current step within that feature.

Comment: Thank you for this @colin0117! I'm sure it will help others too. 
Also for others reading this, here's how you can log this to the console for easy viewing using **cy.now()** _(You can use either 'fail' or 'pass' as the flag, up to you)_

```Cypress.on('fail', (err, runnable) => {
    cy.now('log', "=========\n\n"+JSON.stringify(window.testState)+"\n\n=========")
  })```

Comment: Thanks, @Austin, you might find my comment in this thread helpful too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71755906/printing-output-to-terminal-from-cypress-run/73572137#73572137 . It's showing how to output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.testState.currentScenario.steps[window.testState.currentStep].text
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Could you give more context on how to use this? I've tried it with AND without the use of cy.window() to get the window object and it doesn't work. I get: **Property 'testState' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'**

Trying with cy.window() and I get: **Property 'testState' does not exist on type 'AUTWindow'.**

Comment: This doesn't work - `window.testState.currentStep` is `undefined` in my tests.